# What is the difference between target and bind-target in Angular2 template syntax

Tags: angular

**[UPDATE]: Simple Answer is no diff just two ways to write it.**

---

All:

I am pretty new to Angular2, when I follow its official guide, in [template-syntax section](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html), there is a `Binding syntax: An overview` part, something like:

```
One-way from data source to view target :

{{expression}}
[target] = "expression"
bind-target = "expression"
```

I wonder if anyone could give me a SIMPLE detail what is the diff between

`[target] = "expression"` AND `bind-target = "expression"`

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are equivalent. The alternative was created to be able to avoid conflicts with other tools/frameworks that you might want to use and that use the same syntax for binding.

See also
-[01_templates.md](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/aa98fad338b314cc592ce8d5cc5a552c005c2abc/modules/angular2/docs/core/01_templates.md#summary)
- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#binding-syntax

They are listed as "Short" (`[xxx]` or `{{}}`) and "Canonical" (`bind-xxx`)

There are also def- for #someVar, on- for (). The linked docs list them.

Comment: Thanks, so bind-target is actually NOT randomly chosen name but a fixed prefix "bind-" with a name?

Comment: Yes, the prefix is predefined. There is also `def-` for `#someVar`, `on-` for `()`. The linked docs list them.

Comment: Another question related to this is: what if I want to set a string to an that target? should I use [target] = {{"a string value"}}?

Comment: No, either `[]` or `{{}}` but not both. If you want to add a static string just use `target="a string value"` (or `[target]="a string value"` or `target="{{'a string value'}}"`)

Comment: Ok, say I define a getVal() method which return a number in component, and how can I use it with that target? I tried `target="{{getVal()}}"`  `[target]="getVal()"`  both not work

Comment: Should work. What is `target`? Do you get an error message?

Comment: I just use "target", and tons of error, the first one is: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'target' since it isn't a known native property ("
    <div [ERROR ->][target]="getVal()">{{1+1+getVal()}}</div>
  "): AppComponent@1:9

Comment: If it isn't a property use `[attr.target]=` or `attr.target=`

Comment: Yep, it works, this is so strange. So if I use a customized attribute, I can not even directly use target=""? Then how do I know if a name is native property?

Comment: Above, `[target]="a string value"` should be `[target]=" 'a string value' "`.  You can only do this if `target` is a property of the DOM element or an input property of the component.

Comment: Right, forgot them in this example. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: @MarkRajcok  I declare `@Input() target:string;` in component, but I still got `Can't bind to 'target' since it isn't a known native property ("
    <div [ERROR ->][target]="getVal()">{{1+1+getVal()}}</div>
  "): AppComponent`

Comment: @Kuan, you are mixing DOM element and component.  `@Input` is for a component, so you can't use `<div [target]="...">`, you would have to use `<my-component [target]="..."></my-component>`.  As for DOM elements, you can do something like `<img [src]="...">` since `src` is a DOM property for `img` elements.

Comment: @MarkRajcok thanks, so those variable decorated by `@Input` is used for accept value from external(like parent component), just like the variable inside scope property of a directive definition in Angular1, right?

Comment: @MarkRajcok Another thing I am curious is: what happen if I write the component in template like: `<my-component target="..."></my-component>` Comparing with `<my-component [target]="..."></my-component>`?

Comment: @Kuan I don't know Angular1 well but `@Input() target;` is to pass values from the parent using binding like `<some-comp [target]="valueFromParent"></some-comp>`

Comment: If you use `<my-comp target="someString">` then this is what is written to the DOM. Angular doesn't do anything special about this, except when `target` is an `@Input() target` then `someString` is also passed to the `target` property. With `<my-component [target]="'someString'">` Angular would resolve that binding and pass `someString` to `@Input() target` and no `target` attribute would be written to the DOM.

Comment: Because for the binding syntax `[target]="'someString'"` Angular assumes `someString` is an expression, if you want to pass a literal string you need to wrap it in additional quotes, therefore `"'...'"` instead of just `"..."`